# циклический вывод данных внутри другого цикла

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите что делать,нужно чтобы в каждый select циклически выводились данные не задевая родителей что у меня и не получается ,получается полная бредятина то по 100 раз выводит всех родителей то ничего не выводит.

```
    <?php 
      include("db_connect.php");
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM size");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo '
         <div class="auto-select">
         <div class="options">
         <form id="options" action="../blocks/podbor.php" method="POST">
         <select class="option-year option" name="year">
         <option>'.$row["year"].'</option>
         </select> 
         <select class="option-class option" name="type">
         <option>'.$row["type"].'</option>
         </select>
         <select class="option-type option" name="engine">
         <option>'.$row["engine"].'</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit"class="option option-button" ></div>
         </form>
         </div>
        ';
       }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Зачем первый вызов $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) вне цикла?
2. Расширение mysql устарело, используйте mysqli или pdo
3. Внутри цикла что-то совсем не то, думаю вы хотели получить что-то вроде

```html
 <?php 
      include("db_connect.php");

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM size");
      $yearOptions = $typeOptions = $engineOptions = '';

      while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $yearOptions .= '<option>'.$row["year"].'</option>';
        $typeOptions .= '<option>'.$row["type"].'</option>';
        $engineOptions .= '<option>'.$row["engine"].'</option>';
      }

       echo '
         <div class="auto-select">
         <div class="options">
         <form id="options" action="../blocks/podbor.php" method="POST">
         <select class="option-year option" name="year">'.$yearOptions.'</select> 
         <select class="option-class option" name="type">'.$typeOptions.'</select>
         <select class="option-type option" name="engine">'.$engineOptions.'</select>
         <input type="submit"class="option option-button" >
         </form>
         </div>
         </div>
        ';
       ?>
```

Comment: не совсем,проблема в том что div class="auto-select" должен выводиться много раз как и внутренние select , но получается что Див выводиться либо 1 либо равный количеству данных выносимых в select причем в selecte всегда по одному значению а блоков становится 100500